# Bring Rails gem locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working on a Rails 4 application and one of the requirements is to have all of the Gems that normally go into the Gemfile brought in locally to the machine for use. This includes Rails and after looking at many google search results I am not able to find anyone talking about using the Rails gem locally on a Rails project.

My train of thought here is to clone the rails project from Github locally and then using the bundler config path to target that directory for rails, but I am not sure how well will that solution work or even if it will work.

I will appreciate any input here or if anyone has experience with this situation I will appreciate any insight.

Comment: All gems *are* brought in locally by Bundler. The whole point of Bundler is that it downloads them for you, including all their dependencies. Can you clarify what you're after, and *why*?

Comment: I understand that bundler brings all of the gems and dependencies locally. However, the requirement here is that Bundler does not go anywhere but locally to find the gems, including Rails

Answer (score 0):

The bundle install does that ? 
If you want to install any gem to your project go to the project root on cmd 
$ gem install gemname 
Doing that you locally installed the gem afterwards you want to make sure its loaded to your project so you can run 
$ bundle install 
And simply like that your gem is installed. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have your project on github, then you can clone it using command.

```
git clone github-repository-url
```

And then from that project directory, run command

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

It will install all your rubygems into vendor directory.